# SQL to analyze across different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to find the list names of the top 3 lists with the highest average of avgpoints for movies in the list.

I have a table "movies" with the 'avgpoints' and 'm_id' attributes, a table "lists" with the 'l_id' and 'list' attributes, and a table "combine" that has the 'l_id' and 'm_id' attributes.

How do I group movies by the list they're on if these attributes are separated in different tables? (I'm thinking I need to use group by on lists and movies, then aggregate to find the avg of all the avgpoints for all movies per list, and somehow get the top 3?)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you got the raw text for your comment somewhere so I can shamelessly use it as template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you just need an aggregated query that `JOIN`s all three tables. This query will fetch the top 3 lists with highest average `avgpoints`.

```
SELECT
    l.l_id,
    l.lists,
    avg(avgpoints) avg_avgpoints
FROM 
    lists l
    INNER JOIN combine c ON c.l_id = l.l_id
    INNER JOIN movies  m ON c.m_id = m.m_id 
GROUP BY l.l_id, l.lists
ORDER BY 3 DESC
LIMIT 3
```

If you want to also display lists whose movies could not be found, you would need to change the INNER JOINs to LEFT JOINs.

Comment: @user90823745 : I took this table name from your question : *and a table "combine" that has the 'l_id' and 'm_id' attributes.*

Comment: sorry that was a typo on my end!

Comment: Allright then... Does the query work for you and returns the expected results @user90823745

Comment: I'm only getting 1 row returned using ur query and im not sure why :/

Comment: @user90823745 : if a list does not exist in combine, or its movies cannot be found, it will be ignored. You should maybe check your data.  You may use LEFT JOIN to also display "orphans" lists.

Comment: I updated my answer (there is a slight change in the query)

Comment: hmm it lists 3 now but they all have no entry under avgpoints

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186942/discussion-between-gmb-and-user90823745).